# Jenkins: how to get current time inside Build and pass it to post build

Tags: python, jenkins

So inside my `Build` execute windows batch command I want to get current time and inside `Post Build`  execute windows batch command I want to use this variable when call my `python` script.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Could you provide your current Jenkinsfile and the things you've tried?

Comment: I try to find jenkins variable from this list: http://mv_core_build1:8080/env-vars.html/ but i did not find something that could help me